# Delphi TeeChart ContourSeries StartColor EndColor

Tags: delphi, teechart

I need to copy StartColor and EndColor of series1 to series2
This was working before upgrating TeeChart to version 2014.12.14 :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  k1, k2 : Integer;
  X, Y, Z: real;
begin

  Series2.Clear;
  Series2.NumXValues := 20;
  Series2.NumZValues := 20;
  Series2.ColorEachPoint := false;
  Series2.Filled := true;
  Series2.Marks.Visible := true;
  Series2.AutomaticLevels := true;
  Series2.IrregularGrid := true;

  Series2.StartColor := clYellow;
  Series2.EndColor := clRed;

  for k1 := 1 to 20 do
  begin
      X:= k1 + 1;
      for k2 := 1 to 20 do
      begin
          Y := k2 + 1;
          Z := k1 / 10 + k2 / 10;
          Series2.AddXYZ(X, Z, Y);
      end;
  end;

  Series1.Assign(Series2);
  Series1.StartColor := series2.StartColor;
  Series1.EndColor := series2.EndColor;
end;
```

It seems that these two instructions have no effects:

```
Series1.StartColor := series2.StartColor;
Series1.EndColor := series2.EndColor;
```

Any one have an idea how to fix that?
Thx

Comment: Could you please specify with what version did you find this was working for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug ([ID1065](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1065)). I have found that last version where it worked was 2013.09.131119. I haven't found a workaround to the problem so far. Please feel free to sign up at bugzilla and add yourself to the CC List to receive status updates.